# Rotation Error on Object at 90° and -90°

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, rotation

I'm working on an app which allows the user to rotate an object with iOS touch controls.

I have the following script working fine, with 1 issue that I can't seem to crack.

```
GameObject mainCamera;
public Camera camMain;

// One Touch Rotation
public float rotateSpeed = 0.5f;
static float pitch = 0.0f, yaw = 0.0f, zed = 0.0f, pitchBravo = 0.0f, yawBravo = 0.0f;

// Two Touch Zoom
public float perspectiveZoomSpeed = 0.1f;

// Three Touch Pan
public float panSpeed = 0.5f;
private float xAxis = 0.0f, yAxis = 0.0f;
private float xMain, yMain, zMain;

// Game Objects, Public or Private
private GameObject bravo;

void Update()
{
    // Grabs Bravo
    bravo = GameObject.Find ("bravo");

    pitch = bravo.transform.eulerAngles.x;
    yaw = bravo.transform.eulerAngles.y;

    // One Touch controls rotation of Bravo
    if (Input.touchCount == 1) 
    {
        // Retrieves a single touch and names it TouchZero
        Touch touchZero = Input.GetTouch (0);

        // The start of the rotation will be aligned with Bravo's current rotation
        //pitch = bravo.transform.eulerAngles.x;
        //yaw = bravo.transform.eulerAngles.y;

        // Times the difference in position of touch between frames by the rotation speed. deltaTime to keep movement consistent on all devices
        pitch += touchZero.deltaPosition.y * rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        yaw -= touchZero.deltaPosition.x * rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        // Assigns the new eulerAngles to Bravo
        bravo.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (pitch, yaw, 0.0f);
    }

    // Two Touch contols the Field of View of the Camera aka. Zoom
    if (Input.touchCount == 2)
    {
        mainCamera = GameObject.Find("main");

        // Store both touches.
        Touch touchZero = Input.GetTouch(0);
        Touch touchOne = Input.GetTouch(1);

        // Find the position in the previous frame of each touch.
        Vector2 touchZeroPrevPos = touchZero.position - touchZero.deltaPosition;
        Vector2 touchOnePrevPos = touchOne.position - touchOne.deltaPosition;

        // Find the magnitude of the vector (the distance) between the touches in each frame.
        float prevTouchDeltaMag = (touchZeroPrevPos - touchOnePrevPos).magnitude;
        float touchDeltaMag = (touchZero.position - touchOne.position).magnitude;

        // Find the difference in the distances between each frame.
        float deltaMagnitudeDiff = prevTouchDeltaMag - touchDeltaMag;

        // Otherwise change the field of view based on the change in distance between the touches.
        camMain.fieldOfView += deltaMagnitudeDiff * perspectiveZoomSpeed;

        // Clamp the field of view to make sure it's between 0 and 180.
        camMain.fieldOfView = Mathf.Clamp(camMain.fieldOfView, 2.0f, 30.0f);

        xAxis -= touchOne.deltaPosition.x * panSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        yAxis -= touchOne.deltaPosition.y * panSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        zMain = mainCamera.transform.position.z;

        mainCamera.transform.position = new Vector3 (xAxis, yAxis, zMain);

    }

}
```

With this script the object rotates left and right perfectly, 360°. But when the model is rotated *up and down* it gets to the 90° or -90° mark and bugs out, not allowing the user to carry on rotating.

I've done a bit of research and I believe it may have something to do with *gimbal lock*, my lack of knowledge on the subject means I haven't been able to come up with a fix.

Any help is appreciated.

[GIF of bugged rotation](http://gph.is/2jikO3v)

Comment: Related to your issue: Try using `bravo.transform.Rotate()` with your eulerAngles instead! And unrelated to your issue but you really should initiate your objects outside Update, unless absolutely necessary. Right now you're forcing Unity to Search and find your object and main camera every frame. Initiate them in a `Start()`-method! Nice gif btw! Also, see Rotate documentation here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html